# ionic cordova run android failed. Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I run `ionic cordova run andoroid` It show's build failed.

```
BUILD FAILED in 26s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\Practice\azmaeen\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
(node:14304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14304) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

My `ionic info` project environment is:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v11.9.0
npm  : 6.7.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same issue. I developed one of my apps in **node 8.9** version. Once I upgrade **node 8.9.3 to 11.0** then I faced this issue.

Then I've **Downgrade** my **node version 11.0 to 8.9.3**.

Then I run below command

```
cordova clean android
ionic cordova run android
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is an error with the library `superspawn.js`, try to update that library or change the version.